# Преобразование текста в речь и сохранение в переменную

Tags: python, аудио, преобразование, pyttsx3, синтезатор-речи

Пробую преобразование текста в речь на [python](/questions/tagged/python). Использовал вариант через [pyttsx3](/questions/tagged/pyttsx3) и через win api `win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")`
. В целом реализация не сложная, но единственное не могу найти способ засунуть полученный объект в переменную, а точнее текст → аудио → аудио в переменной.
Подскажите варианты, или идеи, хотя бы, куда копать.
Пример через `pyttsx3`:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.save_to_file('Hello World' , 'test.mp3')
engine.runAndWait()
```

У этой библиотеки есть сохранение в файл, сама переменная `engine` - это объект класса pyttsx3. Его нет смысла засовывать в переменную.
Второй вариант - через `WinApi`:

```
speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
text = "Введите текст, который вы хотели бы озвучить"
print(speaker.SpeakStream)
```

Тут получается воспроизвести текст с помощью встроенного в windows голоса. Но только лишь воспроизведение. Не пойму, как преобразовать объект `speaker` в аудио.
В целом, вопрос такой - как с помощью python перевести речь в аудио, и это аудио засунуть в переменную, что бы дальше с ней работать. И условие таково, что необходимо использовать синтезатор самого ПК (библиотеки наподобие gTTS не подходят).

Comment: Непонятно. Присвойте результат в переменную. В чём проблема?

Comment: @CrazyElf попробовал объяснить что в целом требуется, добавил материал. Суть проблемы в конце.

Comment: для чего сохранять в переменную, что с ней потом будет происходить?

Comment: Представим такой вариант - нужно получить аудио и дальше запулить его на сервер. Я делал так - запись на диск, потом считывание файла в переменную. Но это дополнительные костыли, я хочу миновать этот этап, так как это необходимо для производительности.(не трогать таким образом IO)

Answer (score 0):

Не считаю, что время записи/чтения файла хоть сколько нибудь сравнимы с временем генерациии аудио потока. Однако вот пример кода с использованием библиотеки `gtts`

```
from gtts import gTTS
import io

tts = gTTS('hello', lang='en')
b = io.BytesIO()
tts.write_to_fp(b)

print(b.getvalue()) // выведет b'\xff\xf3D\xc4\x00\x11\xa1*\x10...'
```

Comment: Мне необходимо использование голоса, установленного у меня на ПК. Тут как варианты как раз pyttsx3 или через win api.

Comment: тогда отредактируйте вопрос. нигде не указано, что только эти библиотеки могут использоваться

Comment: подправил. Ну суть вроде уже раскрыл. на самом деле долго ищу решение этой проблемы, нативных способов не вижу.